# How to understand the time reversal symmetry of position operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, operators, time-reversal-symmetry

How to understand the fact that position operator is symmetric under time reversal? I can visualize the momentum and magnetic field being odd under time reversal.
Got the same doubt for Electric field as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily find out which quantities are even and which
are odd upon time-reversal by considering a video showing
physical processes and then comparing it to the time-reversed
video showing the same processes backwards.

See also "[T-symmetry - Effect of time reversal on some variable of
classical physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-symmetry#Effect_of_time_reversal_on_some_variables_of_classical_physics)" for lists of even and odd physical quantities.

#### Even quantities

Obviously the spatial position $\vec{x}$ doesn't change sign
in the time-reversed video. (A body being on the right side in the
original video is still on the right side in the time-reversed video,
not on the left side.)

Also the acceleration $\vec{a}$ doesn't change sign.
(In the original video a ball thrown up and then falling down
is accelerated downwards. Viewed in the reversed video, the
ball is again accelerated downwards, not upwards.)

From Newton's $\vec{F}=m\vec{a}$ you can conclude, force
$\vec{F}$ also doesn't change sign.

And then from the definition of electric field ($\vec{F}=q\vec{E}$),
you can further conclude, the electric field $\vec{E}$ doesn't
change sign.

#### Odd quantities

Obviously in the reversed video time $t$ and velocity $\vec{v}$
have the opposite sign as compared to the original video.

The magnetic field $\vec{B}$ is defined by the Lorentz force
($\vec{F}=q\vec{v}\times\vec{B}$). Because force $\vec{F}$ is even
and velocity $\vec{v}$ is odd, you can conclude the magnetic field
$\vec{B}$ must be odd.

Comment: Great help. In the part where you talk about acceleration, If we shot a video of the ball falling down only, then the reversed video would be showing the ball go up. This looks like acceleration changed sign for me. Sorry, I am very confused about these things. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @NIKHILJOSEPHJOY When you have a ball falling down, its velocity increases, hence accelerated downwards. When you view this in time-reversed video, you have a ball thrown up, with **de**creasing velocity, hence accelerated downwards again. So acceleration does **not** change sign.

Answer (score 0):

Position is ondependent of time. The magnetic field is even under time reversal, the electric field odd. I wouldn't know how to visualize this.